# jsp globals and parameters scope

Tags: java, jsp

i am really new to java, and jsp. so it is understandable that i cant really understand the scope of parameters
here is my code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%!
     String sRony= new String();
     void func() {
        sRony += " - add in func() - ";
    }
%>
<%
     if (request.getParameter("ron")!= null){
         sRony = request.getParameter("ron");
         func();
     }
     if (request.getParameter("sleep")!= null){
        Thread.sleep(2000);
     }

%>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <%=sRony%><%= new java.util.Date() %>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem is that this code is not thread safe. if you'll surf to

```
page.jsp?ron=sleep&sleep=1
```

and at the same time to

```
page.jsp?ron=no_sleep
```

both page will print the "no_sleep", cause the parameter sRony is global.
if i'll remove the `!` from `<%!` the parameter sRony will not be recognized inside `void func()`
i cant figure out how can i declare a parameter that will be per request, and will have the scope inside my function. 
not sure if my platform is important information, i am working on redhat 5.5 64 bit, glassfish server 3.
any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pagescope` and use JSTL instead javacode

```
<c:set var="name1" value="value1" scope="page" />
```